SAMD51 SPI on SERCOM0 not working as expected
I'm trying to use a SAMD51G19 48 pin package to write a very simple SPI program, which will just loopback what's output back into the input, but I'm still new to this processor and haven't done SERCOM on any devices before.
I'm using SERCOM0 on mux mode C which I believe routes SERCOM0 to pins PA13-16. I have configured the DOPO register as 0, so the data out is on pad0, and I've set DIPO to pad 0, too — this is how the datasheet recommends a loopback mode.
When looking at this problem on the debugger, it shows a successful transmission, and when I read the register, it shows a successful read. The only data I read out it 0 though and my signal analyzer doesn't show any data flowing on the pins. I can't find any info about this IC online and can only find SAMD21 articles, they show roughly the same setup, but I can't figure out where mine is wrong.
Edit: Im a bit confused about the PMUX, I made a change and the pmux should be correct now. But I think the SPI is working mostly correctly, I still think the problem is the pin muxing.
Here's the datasheet (section 35).
Here's the code:
//setup SERCOM
MCLK->APBAMASK.bit.SERCOM0_ = 1; //enable SERCOM0 on the APBA bus

//setup SERCOM to use GCLK2 from DFLL48 to 12Mhz
GCLK->GENCTRL[3].reg = GCLK_GENCTRL_DIV(4) | //DIV 4
    GCLK_GENCTRL_GENEN |    //ENABLE GENERATOR
    GCLK_GENCTRL_SRC_DFLL;  //SOURCE IS 48 MHZ DFLL
while(GCLK->SYNCBUSY.bit.GENCTRL3); //wait for generator 3 to sync
GCLK->PCHCTRL[SERCOM0_GCLK_ID_CORE].reg = GCLK_PCHCTRL_GEN_GCLK3 | GCLK_PCHCTRL_CHEN; //setup SERCOM to use GCLK2
//GCLK->PCHCTRL[SERCOM0_GCLK_ID_SLOW].reg = GCLK_PCHCTRL_GEN_GCLK2 | GCLK_PCHCTRL_CHEN;

//PORT->Group[0].DIRSET.reg = (1 << 13) | (1 << 14) | (1 << 15); //This line makes no difference

//MULTIPLEX THE IO PINS
PORT->Group[0].PINCFG[13].bit.PMUXEN = 1; //ENABLE PA13 FOR PERIPHERAL CONTROL
PORT->Group[0].PINCFG[14].bit.PMUXEN = 1; //ENABLE PA14 FOR PERIPHERAL CONTROL
PORT->Group[0].PINCFG[15].bit.PMUXEN = 1; //ENABLE PA15 FOR PERIPHERAL CONTROL
PORT->Group[0].PINCFG[16].bit.PMUXEN = 1; //ENABLE PA16 FOR PERIPHERAL CONTROL
PORT->Group[0].PMUX[6].bit.PMUXO = 0X2; //SET PIN PA13 MUX MODE TO C
PORT->Group[0].PMUX[7].bit.PMUXE = 0x2; //SET PIN PA14 MUX MODE TO C
PORT->Group[0].PMUX[7].bit.PMUXO = 0X2; //SET PIN PA15 MUX MODE TO C
PORT->Group[0].PMUX[8].bit.PMUXE = 0x2; //SET PIN PA16 MUX MODE TO C
//I've also tried PMUX 7,8,8,9
SERCOM0->SPI.CTRLA.bit.SWRST = 1;
while(SERCOM0->SPI.SYNCBUSY.bit.SWRST == 1);

SERCOM0->SPI.CTRLA.bit.MODE = 0x3; // Set SPI to Master mode
//set data in to loop back
SERCOM0->SPI.CTRLA.bit.DIPO = 0x0; // Set Data in to pad3
SERCOM0->SPI.CTRLA.bit.DOPO = 0x0; // Set Do to pad0, Sck to pad1, slave select to pad2

SERCOM0->SPI.BAUD.bit.BAUD = 50;

SERCOM0->SPI.CTRLB.bit.CHSIZE = 0x1; // Set the Character size to 9 bits

SERCOM0->SPI.CTRLA.bit.ENABLE = 1; //enable the SPI module
while(SERCOM0->SPI.SYNCBUSY.bit.ENABLE); //wait for the module to be disabled
SERCOM0->SPI.CTRLB.bit.RXEN = 1;
while(SERCOM0->SPI.SYNCBUSY.bit.CTRLB == 1);
SERCOM0->SPI.INTENSET.bit.DRE = 1;

uint32_t dummy = SERCOM0->SPI.DATA.reg;
if(SERCOM0->SPI.INTFLAG.bit.DRE == 1){
    SERCOM0->SPI.DATA.bit.DATA = (uint32_t) 0xF0;
}
while(SERCOM0->SPI.INTFLAG.bit.RXC == 0);
dummy = SERCOM0->SPI.DATA.bit.DATA;


I found the solution I misread the pinmux table. It doesn't output to pin PA13 it outputs to PA08...
